# PHP form script error

Tags: php, html, forms, webforms, syntax-error

I have created a rather larger html form and I would like the data to send to my email address.

I am using the  POST method and thought my PHP was up to snuff. However, I now get the following error upon submission:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\www\mo\marinecforum\send_form_application.php on line 90.
```

I am having a hell of a time with this. Beyond the error above, I wonder if there is a better way to approach this?

Here is the [PHP code](http://pastebin.com/MKUcgihg).

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error:

This

```
}    mail($to, $email_subject, $message, $headers); ?>
```

to this...

```
mail($to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);
```

Also when you write "$content =" you are resetting variable, you should append by "$content .="

Edit:

Here is entire code, that will probably work... http://sorskod.com/6ERZ455T

EDIT2:

Rename

```
Email Address <input type="text" name="address" />
```

To

```
Email Address <input type="text" name="email" />
```

OR change $_POST["email"] to $_POST["address"] in PHP file.

EDIT3:

Configure mail.

```
ini_set("SMTP","mail.marineconomicforum.org");
ini_set("smtp_port","25");
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'alex@marineconomicforum.org');
```

Comment: Thank you! So much closer, however it the error now says "please enter email" which I did. I think the email field is not being parsed or I've named it incorrectly. Any ideas? Here is the form HTML: http://pastebin.com/AjvvXfPK. Thank you again, this is beyond helpful.

Comment: I edited my answer, email is actually named "address", so sync that in both files.

Comment: Ah, duh that was right in front of my face. I tried both methods and unfortunately, now I am getting a boat load of errors:http://screencast.com/t/rZ1Q3NoXQ4rJ. Here is the new HTML:http://pastebin.com/58fMKdc4 and PHP:http://pastebin.com/VxL4udhk

Comment: This is notice, nothing serious, just put $content = "" on top (to declare it). Second, you don't have sendmail on your localhost. I think it will work on real server.

Comment: Oh sorry that's not localhost, is that Windows server? There is your problem :) jk

Comment: Pardon my stupidity, I am a bit lost. I've run into some issues with our host in the past (e.g. it is too old to support SQL database apparently, hence building this form). Sounds like it also can't handle sendmail?

Comment: Your IIS host is stupid, switch to Linux host. I edited my post, found some sort of solution for your problem, just put this at the top of PHP script (edit3).

Comment: Hmm... that didn't do the trick. Thank you for going above and beyond on this, but I think it might be a lost cause.

Answer (score 0):

You should count your opening and closing `{`'s and `}`'s. You have 1 opening `{` and 3 closing `}`'s so that's 2 too much.

Answer (score 0):

If you go [here](http://pastebin.com/MKUcgihg) to your script.
You have one { on line 2
and three } on lines 51, 90, 107

You will need to change one of your } to { in order to have opened and closed every set {}.